# Merge two spheres to get a new one

Tags: math

How do I calculate a the smallest sphere possible that encapsulates two others spheres?

Every sphere has a center point in 3d space and a radius.

Edit:

Here's my code. I'm trying to implement the merge() function but I don't know how.

```
#include <gl\glm\glm.hpp>

class Sphere
{
public:
    Sphere();
    Sphere(const glm::vec3 &point, float radius);

    void set(const glm::vec3 &point, float radius);
    void reset();
    bool isReset() const;

    const glm::vec3& getCenter() const { return _point; }
    float radius() const { return _radius; }

    void merge(const Sphere &other);

    bool operator==(const Sphere &other) const {
        return (_point == other._point && _radius == other._radius);
    }
    bool operator!=(const Sphere &other) const {
        return !operator==(other);
    }

private:
    glm::vec3 _point;
    float _radius;
};
```

Comment: This is not language specific and too broad. Show your code.

Comment: Do you need help turning the mathematics into code ? If you do show us what you've got so far.  If you need help with the mathematics you're almost certainly asking in the wrong place.

Comment: I edited my post. This shouldn't be too hard so I thought I should ask here..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I hate `glm`, so here's just the math.

Suppose your two spheres have radii `r1, r2` and centers `c1, c2`. The enclosing sphere has center `C` radius `R`:

[image]

If the spheres enclose each other:

`|c1 - c2| + r1 < r2` or vice versa, take the larger sphere.

Otherwise from the diagram it is clear that

- `R = (r1 + r2 + |c1 - c2|) / 2`
- `C = c1 + (c2 - c1) * (R - r1) / |c2 - c1|` (linear interpolation)

Where `c1, c2, C` are *vectors*, and `|v|` is the magnitude of vector `v`.

Comment: I think there are cases when this could go wrong. R comes out wrong when the two spheres have the same center point. i.e. `sphere1 = (vec3(0,0,0), 10.0f); sphere2 = (vec3(0,0,0), 20.0f);`. R comes out 15 where it should be 20.

Comment: Actually this would be covered by the special case of one sphere encapsulating the other.

Comment: In the non special case the center can be rewritten as `C = (c1 + c2 + (r1 - r2) * (c1 - c2)/ |c1 - c2|) / 2` which is nicer because it makes it more obvious how inverting circles 1 and 2 leaves the formula the same